# Who was the first person to repent?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, provenance

Who was first person in history to do complete teshuva (repentance)?

Answer (score 9):

The Midrash (Bereishis Rabbah [84](http://www.tsel.org/torah/midrashraba/vayeshev.html):19) says that it was Reuven. For this he was rewarded by having his descendant, the prophet Hosea, be the one to issue the call to teshuvah "Shuvah Yisrael" ([Hos. 14:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1314.htm#2), the haftarah of Shabbos Shuvah).

Comment: what about Cain ?

Comment: It's not so clear whether he actually did teshuvah; it depends on whether his words Gen. 4:13 (גדול עוני מנשוא) are a statement of regret ("my sin is too great to bear") or a rhetorical question ("is my sin too great to bear?"). Ibn Ezra and Ramban hold with the first approach, while Rashi (to that verse, and also to 4:16) says that he was insincere.

Comment: Also, Ramban says he had charata and viduy, but we don't know about azivas hacheit which is the difficult part.

Comment: Isn't there the medrish that Adam said Mizmor Shir L'yom Hashabbos after hearing that Cain had repented?  ("I struck a deal with G-d" or something like that.)

Comment: There's also the liturgy from ... is it Yom Kippur or Selichos? with each stanza listing a famous Biblical character who did repentance; I think it starts with Adam and Cain.  Someone fill me in please?

Comment: That midrash is in Bereishis Rabbah 22:13, as the third of three views regarding what the Torah means when it tells us that "Cain went out from before Hashem" (Gen. 4:16). That opinion says that he was happy to have been forgiven, and that Adam took heart from that and went on to do teshuvah himself; the other two opinions (one of which Rashi follows), on the other hand, view Cain's "going out" negatively.

Comment: The liturgy you mention is the selichah beginning הורית דרך תשובה, which in the Ashkenazic custom is said on Tzom Gedaliah, and indeed Adam and Cain are its first two examples of teshuvah. The bottom line is that there do seem to be variant opinions on whether Cain did teshuvah, and of what sort; YDK may be right in saying that his teshuvah was incomplete.

Comment: ...and of Vayetzei for Ashkenazim and of Tisha B'av Mincha for Sephardim.

Comment: The source brought in http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17145/603 seems to indicate that Kayin's Teshuva was incomplete.

Comment: Doesn't Judah get credit for causing Reuben's admitting? From Rashi on Vezot Habracha by admitting what he did with Tamar. Maybe Reuben had done everything *but* viduy?

Answer (score 9):

The commentary often attributed to [the *Rosh*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asher_ben_Jehiel) and sometimes to one of his students, to [*B'reshis* 4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0104):16 (after *Kayin*'s banishment), [reads](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14033&pgnum=7):

> ויצא קין יצא כמעלים מבוראו ונגלה לו הקב״ה וא״ל גדול עונך מנשא כיון ששמע קין התחיל לעשות תשובה ואמר גדול עוני מנשוא ואמר אתה טוען עליונים ותחתונים ונקראת נושא עון אמר לו הקב״ה אתה עשית תשובה אבל מחצה עד שהוא יוצא פגע בו אדם א״ל ומה יצא בדינך א״ל אלמלא שהודיתי הייתי אבוד מן העולם באותה שעה תמה אדם ואמר טוב להודות לה׳

Or, in my own, loose translation:

> "*Kayin* went out" [a quotation from 4:16] — he went out like someone hiding from his creator, and God appeared to him, saying "Your sin is too great to excuse". When *Kayin* heard this, he started doing *t'shuva*, saying "My sin is too great to excuse" and "You bear what is above and what is below and [have been called](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%96) the one who excuses sin". God told him "You did *t'shuva*, but halfway".
>
> As *Kayin* was leaving, *Adam* met him and said "How did your court case come out?". *Kayin* told him "Had I not admitted, I'd be gone from the world". At that time, *Adam* marveled and [said](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A6%D7%91_%D7%91) "It is good to admit to God".

Answer (score 7):

Avraham was Chozer Beteshuvah from a life of Idolatry to recognizing the true Boreh Olam (creator of the universe).  See Rambam Hilchos Avodah Zorah.

Comment: Good point! And indeed the Midrash (Bereishis Rabbah 39:8) has Avraham worrying about these sins of his youth, and Hashem reassuring him that they've vanished like the dew.

Answer (score 1):

(a) (R. Yirmeyah ben Elazar): The years that Adam ha'Rishon was in Niduy (excommunication due to his sin) he propagated damaging spirits. "Va'Ychi Adam Sheloshim u'Me'as Shanah va'Yoled bi'Dmuso k'Tzalmo", implies that before this, he fathered things not in his image.

(b) Question (Beraisa - R. Meir): [After he sinned] Adam ha'Rishon was a great Chasid. When he saw that death was decreed on the world through himself, for 130 years he fasted, separated from his wife (Kayin and Hevel were already born - Rashi Bereishis 4:1) and wore belts of fig shoots on his flesh [to afflict himself].

http://dafyomi.co.il/eruvin/points/ev-ps-018.htm